# How can I restrict access to listing users via JSON:API but allow users to edit their own accounts?

Tags: 9

I am building a webapp with Drupal using JSON:API.  When users have permission to view accounts, then they can go to `/jsonapi/user--user/` and get a list of all the accounts on the site.

I don't want to expose this information, so I tried disabling access to the resource in an EventSubscriber [as described in the docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/customizing-resources#s-example):

```
  public function disableResourceType(ResourceTypeBuildEvent $event) {
    if ($event->getResourceTypeName() === 'user--user') {
      $event->disableResourceType();
    }
  }
```

**However, when I disable access to the resource, users can no longer update their profiles via JSON:API.**

So how do I restrict access to GET but allow PATCH, POST, and DELETE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a routing event subscriber [as described here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/security-considerations#s-6-limit-which-entity-bundles-may-be-created-or-editedby-removing-some-routes):

```
namespace Drupal\MYMODULE\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Class MYMODULEJsonApiLimitingRouteSubscriber.
 *
 * Remove GET route for users.
 *
 */
class MYMODULEJsonApiLimitingRouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection): void {
    foreach ($collection as $name => $route) {
      $defaults = $route->getDefaults();
      if (!empty($defaults['_is_jsonapi']) && !empty($defaults['resource_type'])) {
        $methods = $route->getMethods();
        if (in_array('GET', $methods) && $name === 'jsonapi.user--user.collection') {
          $collection->remove($name);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notes

- JSON:API module has the concept of "collection" routes.  These are the routes that list all of your entities, like `user--user`, so by disabling GET access to the collect route, users will not be able to get a list of all users, but they will still be able to get their individual accounts and make updates.
- If you use [JSON:API Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_extras) or custom code to rename the user route, the route name will change!  For example, I renamed `user--user` to `users`, so my route is actually `jsonapi.users.collection`.

As a bonus, if you want to ensure that users can only access their own account, and not others, you need to implement `hook_entity_access()`:

```
function MYMODULE_user_access(UserInterface $user, string $operation, AccountInterface $account): AccessResult {
  if (!($account->hasPermission(PermissionCheck::AdministerUsers->value))) {
    $current_user_id = $account->id();
    $user_being_accessed_id = $user->id();
    if ($current_user_id === $user_being_accessed_id) {
      return AccessResult::allowed();
    }
  }
  return AccessResult::forbidden();
}
```

I came up with this solution based on [this comment by bradjones1](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3282663#comment-14555469).